# Github error: Invalid notebook missing attachment image.png...but no attachment in file

Tags: image, github, jupyter-notebook

I committed a ipynb file to github. I'm getting an error that says "Invalid notebook missing attachment image.png". Initially, the notebook included a reference to a jpg file (which I had also committed to the repository), but I deleted the markdown cell containing that. Since deleting that cell I tried re-uploading and when that didn't work, I tried creating a new repository, but I got the same error. I can see other ipynb files on github, even my own. Any ideas? Repository is here: https://github.com/cvanort/AmesHousingPricePredictions

[image: The error]

Comment: I had the same issue. However, after removing the cells that have mentioned the attachments, it got fixed. In your case, I believe you provided the image.png file (because you notebook is loading now).

Comment: Yes, thank you! The whole notebook apparently disappeared because I had a link to an invalid png in another cell. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

simply you look in your notebook for (image.png). if you find them you just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried removing the (invalid) image.png after looking into your notebook and the error persists, you can perhaps try to clear all outputs before making the next commit.

You can do that by selecting:
`edit --> clear all outputs`

The reason is that notebooks can store some metadata (sometimes, the error-generating ones) when the cells are run which might be causing the error in your case.