# Github invalid file error in uploading google colab file

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to upload a Google Colab notebook to GitHub, but I keep getting the error:

```
Invalid notebook 
missing attachment.
```

[image: error]

I went back and deleted the line for that png but still after resaving the notebook and trying to upload it again it says the same thing just for another png.
Is there a way to fix this without deleting every png in my notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Check first, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71112085/6309), if you have a  a link to an invalid png in another markdown cell.

In other words, the png might not be the issue (no need to delete it).
But an invalid reference to a png with the same name might trigger the error.